# Not able to open jupyterlab

Tags: python-3.x, jupyter, jupyter-lab

When I write jupyterlab from my command prompt to open jupyter it is giving me an error "cannot import name 'DEFAULT_STATIC_FILES_PATH' from 'notebook'". What is the reason and how can I come over it?

Comment: You may be missing `jupyter_server` installation. Have you tried upgrading your packages with `pip install -U jupyter_server notebook jupyterlab`?

Comment: Earlier reported in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65930449/importerror-cannot-import-name-default-static-files-path-when-trying-to-run-j